# WHERE command is not working

Tags: sql, influxdb

In using `Influxql`, when I try the following command

```
select "P_askbid_midprice1" from "/HFT/Data_HFT/OrderBook/DCIX_OB" limit 50
```

I got the following result

```
name: /HFT/Data_HFT/OrderBook/DCIX_OB
time                 P_askbid_midprice1
----                 ------------------
2015-05-30T00:00:00Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:01Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:02Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:03Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:04Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:05Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:06Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:07Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:08Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:09Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:10Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:11Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:12Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:13Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:14Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:15Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:16Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:17Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:18Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:19Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:20Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:21Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:22Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:23Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:24Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:25Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:26Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:27Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:28Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:29Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:30Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:31Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:32Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:33Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:34Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:35Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:36Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:37Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:38Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:39Z 0
2015-05-30T00:00:40Z 0
```

But with the command

```
select "P_askbid_midprice1" from "/HFT/Data_HFT/OrderBook/DCIX_OB" WHERE time > '2016-05-30' and time < '2015-05-31'
```

I got nothing from that command even if it is pretty similar to the previous one.

What is the problem with that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `or` statement instead of an `and` statement. Time cannot be both "after" May 2016 **and** "before" May 2015. It has to be one **or** the other.

```
select "P_askbid_midprice1" 
from "/HFT/Data_HFT/OrderBook/DCIX_OB" 
WHERE 
    time > '2016-05-30' 
    or time < '2015-05-31'
```